# WCF per connection server certificate validation

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I'm trying to bypass https certificate validation only to our own testing environment (multiple machines), while trying to keep certificate validation for all the other connection.

From reading online, most (if not all) WCF related suggestion seems to point to the something similar of following

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

However, this is a global setting and I would like to apply this for only a specific connection. Is this even possible/supported usage scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCert);

public static bool ValidateCert(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    string requestHost;

    if(sender is string)
    {
        requestHost = sender.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = sender as HttpWebRequest;

        if(request != null)
        {
            requestHost = request.Host;
        }
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestHost) && requestHost == "my_test_machine")
        return true;

    return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
}
```

Note the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) on the `sender` parameter:

> sender parameter passed to the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback can be a host string name or an object derived from WebRequest (HttpWebRequest, for example) depending on the CertificatePolicy property

Disclaimer - I didn't test this, I wrote it based on the documentation. YMMV.

Comment: I was hoping there is a per connection setting that I can set. I'd like to avoid having to check the host on a global validator. Seems awfully ineffective. However, this does the job, I'll award the point if there's no better answer close to bounty end time.

Comment: I'm not aware of a per-connection setting but perhaps someone more enlightened than me will chip in. If it's only when testing you could just wrap the code in an #if DEBUG...

Comment: Since there's no obvious way that you can perform this per WCF connection, this is the closest thing to it. Too bad you cannot simply apply certificate validation to individual connections, would be really helpful.

Comment: This however, won't work for WSDL services. Any ideas for that one?

Answer (score 11):

I was finally able to find a *real* solution when using .net 4.5.

This code allows you to use a custom validator only for a specific WCF client.

It has been tested against BasicHttpBinding with `BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport`.

There is a new property named [`SslCertificateAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificaterecipientclientcredential.sslcertificateauthentication) in `ClientBase.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate`.

You can initialize this property with a [`X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.x509servicecertificateauthentication) where you can provide a custom `X509CertificateValidator`.

For example:

```
// initialize the ssl certificate authentication
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
{
   CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom,
   CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomValidator(serverCert)
};

// simple custom validator, only valid against a specific thumbprint
class CustomValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
    private readonly X509Certificate2 knownCertificate;

    public CustomValidator(X509Certificate2 knownCertificate)
    {
        this.knownCertificate = knownCertificate;
    }

    public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (this.knownCertificate.Thumbprint != certificate.Thumbprint)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Unknown certificate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This inspired for my anwer below

Answer (score 3):

Seems like in .NET 4.5 you can do the following:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
```

I did not realize it initially, as you actually have to cast result of `Create` method to `HttpWebRequest`, as abstract `WebRequest` does not contain this delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can disable SSL cert validation per client/channel with this code:

```
var noCertValidationAuth = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication() 
{ 
    CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None 
};
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = noCertValidationAuth;
```

It is actually a variation of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406845/981396) in this thread, so kudos there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose you a more "kosher" way to do it (from the point of information security):

1. [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a self-signed unique certificate for your developer machine
2. [Add](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx) this certificate to "Trusted root" certificate store on your test service instance
3. Add the certificate to application's allowed list (if it exists)

This will allow you to work with your service without creating "backdoors" in code. This also will allow you to limit test access to test environment only while having same code both on Test and Prod instances.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we're aware of this approach. While this would work, this will require us to re-deploy the certificate on every machine that we need to have test connection so this is not really what we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is place a setting in Your web.config file.

Then in Your code check the value in the web.config file. Then set the certificate validation depending on that value.

**Edit**

One option is:

```
String url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

Another is: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Feb/11/HttpWebRequest-and-Ignoring-SSL-Certificate-Errors

**Edit 2**

Try something like this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += customXertificateValidation;


private static bool customXertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate cert, 
X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    if (check something here)
   {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, as soon as I set ServerCertificateValidationCallback, it'll affect all future connections so I'm not sure how this can be achieved through web.config. Please provide an example.

Comment: This may be true for HttpWebRequest, but I'm looking for setting specifically for WCF.

Comment: it can be achived by setting specific endpoint with http request and mark deletegates for usages only with this endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I used a flag in the Web.config file to indicate when a certificate is self-signed 
and we also know that we are in a development environment:

```
<add key="isSelfSignedCertificate" value="true"/>
```

In the code we must check this flag to apply the certificate validation exception:

```
using System.Net;

bool isSelfSignedCertificate = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isSelfSignedCertificate"]);

if (isSelfSignedCertificate)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
}
```